# What is the correct foreach expression to update mysql rows from this while statement?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, foreach

I have found similar questions including one on stackoverflow here: [Update echoed data using WHILE loop. Only updates one record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16116051/update-echoed-data-using-while-loop-only-updates-one-record)

I have been having a problem using these examples for my use and am looking for a specific foreach expression to use. I'm sure the solution is very simple.

Table "test":

```
+--------+
|id|text |
+--+-----+
|0 |Text1|
+-+------+
|1 |Text2|
+-+------+
|2 |Text3|
+-+------+
|4 |Text4|
+-+------+
|5 |Text5|
+-+------+
|6 |Text6|
+-+------+
|7 |Text7|
+-+------+
```

A PDO prepared statement is executed with a select query selecting all the rows in the table "test". The rows are fetched in a while statement and each row is placed into inputs for the user to change the "text" field data as so:

```
$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY id");
$sth->execute();

echo '<form class="ajax" method="post">';

while($row = $sth->fetch()) {
echo '<input type="text" name="id" class="id" value="'.$row['id'].'" />
<input type="text" name="text" class="text" value="'.$row['text'].'" />'; 
}

echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></form>';
```

On submit the database is (supposed to) update all text fields by the id.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {  
  $text = $_POST['text'];
  $id = $_POST['id'];
  $sql = "UPDATE test SET text = :text WHERE id = :id";
  $sth = $db->prepare($sql);
  $sth->execute(array(':text'=>($text),':id' => ($id)));
}
```

Currently only the last row is updated in the database and I believe that I need to place my prepared update statement in a foreach loop.

Something like this:

```
foreach($something as $something => $somethingElse) {
  $text = $_POST['text'];
  $id = $_POST['id'];
  $sql = "UPDATE test SET text = :text WHERE id = :id";
  $sth = $db->prepare($sql);
  $sth->execute(array(':text'=>($text),':id' => ($id)));
}
```

What is the correct expression to use here? Or, am I barking up the wrong tree in some way?

Thanks

Sam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your inputs to this.

```
while($row = $sth->fetch()) {
echo '<input type="text" name="id[]" class="id" value="'.$row['id'].'" />
<input type="text" name="text[]" class="text" value="'.$row['text'].'" />'; 
}
```

Then your loop

```
for($i=0; $i<count($_POST['id']); $i++) {
    $id = $_POST['id'][$i];
    $text = $_POST['text'][$i];
    $sql = "UPDATE test SET text = :text WHERE id = :id";
    $sth = $db->prepare($sql);
    $sth->execute(array(':text'=>($text),':id' => ($id)));
}
```